# Possible to do conditionals on embeds?

Tags: conditionals, embeds

Is it possible to do conditionals for embeds? For example,lets say I have this very simple template, `test/foo`

```
{if foo}
   yes
{if:else}
   no
{/if}
```

In other templates, I want to use this embed in a conditional.

{if '{embed="test/foo"}' == 'yes'}
   Output is yes
{if:else}
   Output is no
{/if}

Unfortunately, when I tried this approach, what I got was always a `no`, even if I set `test/foo` template to yes.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this just not possible?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Explain a little better, please.

Answer (score 4):

This way is not possible because of [ExpressionEngine’s Parse Order](http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf)

> 1. Parse advanced conditionals
> 2. Process embedded templates

With your code you don't have "yes" in conditionals when EE parses it, you have "{embed="test/foo"}"

Comment: Is there any alternatives to achieve this?

Comment: is dependent to what exactly you have in embed template and why do you need to use it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do what you're looking for with [Stash](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stash), using [stash:embed](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bstash%3aembed%7D). With the Stash embed you should be able to manipulate the process and parse stage so that it will run before the advanced conditional (see Max's answer).